# Should an HTTP server respond with a more specific Content-Type than was requested?

Tags: http, mime-types, content-negotiation

For example, if the request was

```
GET /feed.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: www.nowhere123.com
Accept: application/xml
```

... would it be admissible for a server to respond with a header `Content-Type: application/atom+xml` (even though the request had `Accept: application/xml`), or should it serve the same body but with `Content-Type: application/xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A server is allowed to ignore the header field, so yes, sending something more specific is ok. There's a reason why HTTP messages are self-descriptive. (see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.5.3.2.p.7)